# remove all autogenerated ._* duplicates from a repository

Tags: linux, git, macos, svn

I run XAMPP-VM for OS X and got a site folder that is pushed in svn. Once svn push is done, my colleague on the other side sees the site folder with `._*` duplicates of all existing files.

My site is:

```
- index.php
- contacts.php
- uploads/dosmth.txt
```

they all become:

```
- index.php
- ._index.php
- contacts.php
- ._contacts.php
- uploads/dosmth.txt
- uploads/._dosmth.txt
```

Tried using git with `.gitignore` containing `._*` - no result (`.*` works, but `._*` doesn't). Tried using GUI svn's and stuff like GitKraken, expecting such function may be in place, but it seems it's not the case.

I understand those `._*` files are generated by Mac by default, - but it's strange however that they are added in my situation as I am working on  Linux VM (XAMPP-VM) and using Linux terminal to push. My goal is to get rid of `._*` files.

Comment: found a button "ignore" in smart svn, which solves it, but its sort of a clumsy way, soy would still be nice to have some more solid solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on Linux:

```
find . -name "._*" -print |xargs rm.
```

Try it first without the `|xargs rm` part, just to validate that the find will actually list the files you want deleted.

Comment: `find . -name "._*" -delete`

Comment: I learned most of my unix a long time ago, -delete did not exist "back then".  But you are right, newer find now have -delete option.

Comment: Me too. I remember times when `find` didn't have option `-delete` :-)

Comment: thanks a lot, this did solved it. Even thought `|xargs rm.` did not actually delete files, `|xargs rm -rf` did the job for me. Did not yet test out `find . -name "._*" -delete` but seems a bit more easy to memorize for a person not too much into linux like myself. thanks guys for advise.